# Using KKT to minimize projection $f(x_1, x_2,..., x_n) = x_n$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

For fixed, finite $n$, let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I am trying to solve a problem of the form:

Minimize: $$f(x) = x_n$$
such that
$$g_j(x) \leq 0; \ j \in \{1,...,m\}$$
$$h_\ell(x)=0; \ \ell \in \{1,..., r\}$$

What I tried was to use KKT conditions but I have a problem. A minimum is a point where $\nabla_x f = 0$, and, since I am working with the projection $f(x) = x_n$, the gradient is $\nabla_xf=(0,0,...,1)^T$. Does that mean I can't use this method? If so, what can I try?

Comment: If the solution point is strictly inside the feasible region, then it is true that $\nabla_x f(x) = 0$ but if the solution point is located at the boundary you can have $\nabla_x f(x)\ne  0$ In your case, the solution is always at the boundary because $f(x)$ is linear.

Comment: @Cesareo So I just have to solve the equivalent problem with $g_j(x) = 0$?

Comment: Don't forget that $h_l(x)=0$ composes also the boundary.

Comment: Yes, I meant the same problem, but changing the inequalities to equations and keeping everything else the same.

Comment: If you have $g(x) = 0$ then $\nabla_x (f\circ g)(x^*) = 0$

Comment: I understand that statement, but I can't see where you're pointing at with it.

Comment: Then I did not understand what you wanted with ... changing the inequalities to equations and keeping everything else the same...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102936/discussion-between-the-bosco-and-cesareo).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compute a global minimum, you need to have a convex cost function and a convex feasible domain (with a non null interior), thus your function g must be convex and h must verify certain assumptions (affine is suffcient). In such a case, the KKT conditions are expressed as :

1- gradient(Lagrangian(x,y)) = 0 ; where y represents the dual vairables

2- g(x)<=0 ; h(x)=0 primal feasibility

3- y>=0 dual feasibility

4-  = 0 complementarity slackness

=> The lagrangian integrates the cost function f, the verification of the constraints (g(x)<=0 and h(x)=0)

=> The complementarity 
slackness is the reformulation of what @Cesareo said in his comment, if you are inside your domain the dual variables are null. If you are in the frontier, they take non null values thus your gradient is not necessarily null.